# ClosedXML (Excel): dos validaciones en una celda?

Tags: excel, validación, celdas

quiero validar una celda de un Excel hecho con ClosedXML y que tenga dos validaciones a la vez, como puedo hacer??? He probado con esto pero sólo me pilla la última validación... En el código se ve como valida que la celda x,y del Excel tenga una fecha mayor que una fecha de firma pasada y a la vez dicha fecha sea igual o menor que la fecha actual...

```
ws.Cell(x, y).DataValidation.Date.GreaterThan(fechaFirma);

ws.Cell(x, y).DataValidation.Date.EqualOrLessThan(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Como puedo editar mi propio post?

Comment: puedes darle click en la parte de abajo de post donde dice editar o tambien en este link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/496590/edit

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Nada, ya lo he solucionado, al final he sustituido las dos validaciones por una, con un ‘between’ me ha servido para validar que el valor de la celda esté entre dos fechas:

```
         //ws.Cell(x, y).DataValidation.Date.GreaterThan(fechaFirma);
         //ws.Cell(x, y).DataValidation.Date.EqualOrLessThan(DateTime.Now);
          ws.Cell(x, y).DataValidation.Date.Between(fechaFirma.AddDays(1), DateTime.Now);
```